# dotnet publish doesn't create a bin folder for Azure Functions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am currently running a dotnet publish on an azure function with the following Directory.Build.targets

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_IsFunctionsSdkBuild Condition="$(_FunctionsTaskFramework) != ''">true</_IsFunctionsSdkBuild>
    <_FunctionsExtensionsDir>$(TargetDir)</_FunctionsExtensionsDir>
    <_FunctionsExtensionsDir Condition="$(_IsFunctionsSdkBuild) == 'true'">$(_FunctionsExtensionsDir)bin</_FunctionsExtensionsDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyExtensionsJson" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsAndCopyContentFiles">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Overwritting extensions.json file with one from build." />

    <Copy Condition="$(_IsFunctionsSdkBuild) == 'true' AND Exists('$(_FunctionsExtensionsDir)\extensions.json')"
          SourceFiles="$(_FunctionsExtensionsDir)\extensions.json"
          DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)bin\extensions.json"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
          ContinueOnError="true"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However it is currently failing as it can't find the path.

> bin\Release\netstandard20\publish\bin

This is happenening both locally and in the Azure Dev Ops build pipeline

However if I manually create this folder location everything works fine. I have other projects that do exactly the same with no issues and no delta between them and the one project that is causing the issue.

The functions is set to v2

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard20</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there anything I am missing why this folder doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. I added

```
  <Target Name="MakeMyDir" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDir)bin" />
  </Target>
```

to the Build.Targets which ensures the directory is created before the copy

Comment: If this can solve your problem, you can mark it as the answer no matter it's a work around or a solution.